# Download file from dropbox on android and play it

Tags: android, file, dropbox

I try to download video file from dropbox in android application,
without logging with a dropbox account.

I found this explanation
https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en
but the problem is I don't have the path of the downloaded file and can't open it 
inside of the application.

Hope the question clear enough.
Thanks in advance!
Ella

Comment: The path for downloaded files is generally `/sdcard/download/`
Are you talking about the name of the downloaded file instead?

Comment: I'm talking about the the of the file,and also I would like to know if I can change the download path to the following: /sdcard/myapplication/

Answer (score 0):

If you're Starring a file in Dropbox (which makes it a favorite, stores it to phone for quick access, and keeps file updated), then path would be: `sdcard0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch`. The naming of `sdcard0` may vary based on your phone model.

If you Export a file, you can choose to Save to SD Card, which then allows you to browse for the location you want to save to. There's no options to control the default save location, so your best option for a consistent (quick) save location is to use the above Favorites method.

Additionally, the Favorites method reflects your directory structure of the file in your Dropbox folder, so you could depend on Favorited files being accessible in a location that you control, based on how your Dropbox files are organized.

You can then use something like ES File Explorer to browse to files that you've Favorited, and create shortcuts to those files/folders on your Android desktop.